# Внутренние определения должны быть в начале тела процедуры

Tags: lisp, scheme

Цитата из SICP:

> Внутренние определения должны быть в начале тела процедуры. За последствия запуска программ, перемешивающих определения и их использование, администрация ответственности не несет.

Пример правильного кода

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (define (good-enough? guess)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) 0.001))
  (define (improve guess)
    (average guess (/ x guess)))
  (define (sqrt-iter guess)
    (if (good-enough? guess)
     guess
    (sqrt-iter (improve guess))))
  (sqrt-iter 1.0))
```

это значит что я не могу поступить вот так? -

```
(define (test x)
  (define (test2) (* x x))
  (test2)
  (define (test3) (+ x x))
  (test3))
```

Или подразумевается что я должен объявить его до использования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандарте языка Scheme - R5RS ([здесь](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs/Internal-definitions.html)) написано так же. Я запустил этот код в Chez Scheme и получил:

```
Exception: invalid context for definition (define (test3) (+ x x))
```

EDIT:

Есть и контрпример. Я запустил тот же код в Chibi Scheme (R7RS) и теперь он заработал правильно. Тот же результат в Racket.
Но всё же порядок определений имеет значение. Когда я запустил:

```
(define (test x)
   (test1)
   (define (test1) (* x x)))
```

получил:

```
ERROR in test: undefined variable: test1
Searching for modules exporting test1 ...
```

Comment: Вы имеете второй пример?